# Azure Bitnami WordPress: Issues Configuring Varnish - Documentation seems inaccurate

Tags: wordpress, azure, varnish, bitnami

This [documentation for Bitnami Wordpress Varnish configuration](https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/apps/wordpress/configuration/configure-varnish/)
seems out of date. Below, I've provided a screen shot with numbering corresponding to the numerous issues.

(Note: If you read the documentation, I'm using "Approach A: System packages")

Command #1.) This referenced file doesn't exist in my installation to copy: /opt/bitnami/varnish/etc/varnish/default.vcl. There is no etc directory in the varnish directory, and doing a find for default.vcl doesn't pull back any results.

Command #2.) I browsed and found is this dir and file: /opt/bitnami/varnish/conf/wordpress.vcl.disabled/wordpress.vcl.disabled The file seems to have contents of a default Varnish configuration file for WordPress - so thinking that this must be it, I copied it to /opt/bitnami/varnish/conf/wordpress.vcl

Command #3.) I ran this command, pointing to /opt/bitnami/varnish/conf/wordpress.vcl I had copied from that found file.  That command provided on errors, but also no output upon submission.

Command(step) #4: Hoping that last step work, I proceeded to 'Enable and start the Varnish (TM) Service' - and on that page immediately ran into more issues. This command won't be successful because there is no varnish directory in /opt/bitnami/scripts `[ -f /opt/bitnami/scripts/varnish/start.sh.disabled ] && sudo mv /opt/bitnami/scripts/varnish/start.sh.disabled /opt/bitnami/scripts/varnish/start.sh`

[image: screenshot of Bitnami documentation]

I'm stuck and could use help deciphering the documentation as it doesn't seem to reflect the installation I'm using. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've just checked the WP image and could follow the documentation without issues. Since it is related to Bitnami configuration, I would suggest open a case on Bitnami community forum.

Comment: Thank you. The Bitnami forums are kind of difficult to post to, but lack of response here along with your comment meant I fought to get a topic open there.  I got a post up and working with support, and will try to post the resolution back here if I am lucky enough to realize it.